# Google Cloud Storage API and Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to work with node.js client library for accessing googleAPI (https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client).
I am trying to insert bucket and object using google cloud storage API. I can successfully list the buckets of my project's storage. Also can retrieve specific bucket from the storage. But unable to insert the bucket or object.

Code which do the API call:

```
 googleapis.discover('storage', 'v1').execute(function(err,client){
    if(err)
     {
         console.log(err);
     }
  //insert bucket
  client.storage.buckets.insert({'project': "myproject_id",
                                 'resource': {'name': "mystorage-bucket"}})
                                  .withAuthClient(auth)
                                  .execute(function(err,result){
                                  console.log('error :',err,'inserted:',result);
                                 });
```

This is what shows in the log:

```
    error : { errors: 
                    [ { domain: 'global', 
                        reason: 'required', 
                        message: 'Required' } ],
              code: 400,
              message: 'Required' } inserted: null
```

Any indication what is "Required", how to provide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource object should go as the second parameter of `.insert` like so:

```
client.storage.buckets.insert({ 
  'project': "myproject_id"
},
{
  'name': "mystorage-bucket"
}).withAuthClient(auth).execute(callback);
```

Comment: Is there any example to insert object? I am trying to insert simple text objet to bucket. But showing same error message:'Required' in the log.

Comment: You'll need to use withMedia to upload the object and metadata to a bucket. Example on how to use .withMedia here: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples/mediaupload.js

Comment: wow..it works.Thanks a lot.I m quite newbie with node.js and totally no hint what to do. Thanks Ryan.